# Showing author box on post detail page

Tags: plugins, php, functions

Being new to word-press as well php i am struck at a point.
I am trying to display author information along with his picture in the post and have successfully able to fetch all the data from gravatar.com and able to display it on the right hand side bar successfully.

Currently this box is coming through out the website, but my requirement is that it should only be displayed when reader is on the post detail page. As per my little knowledge of word-press, i kw that each post will going to relate to some category. How can i able to show the author box to only post detail page and hide it from all other places.Any help in this regard will be much helpful

just to edit i have added following code

```
<?php  $category_ids = remove_element(get_all_category_ids(),'274');
     if (in_category($category_ids)) { ?>
```

this code is not working but if i pass a single category id to `in_category()` function like

```
 <?php  
         if (in_category('8')) { ?>
```

if block is working fine.i am clueless what is going wrong Thanks in advance

Comment: Have look at this plugin as it may save you a lot of coding http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-avatars/ to show the Author info. Doesn't solve the single only problem.

Comment: i saw that plugin before but i have to fetch a lot of information from the gravatar so can't use that plugin.Thanks for the suggestion an pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your code for the author appearing (what files > category / post / single?)?

I would guess you have the author code within either a category or post template file, simply add the author code to the single template file (create single.php if you don't have one) and remove from the upper level files.

** To answer your question (based on comments below)

You would want to create a new sidebar template (sidebar-single.php) and pull that sidebar into your single.php

Comment: I have put the code in sidebar.php myself

Comment: so you would want to create a new sidebar template (sidebar-single.php) and pull that sidebar into your single.php

Comment: :Thanks for the help but being new can you help me to understand these lines "simply add the author code to the single template file (create single.php if you don't have one) and remove from the upper level files. " since i already have single.php in side my theme file

Comment: paste the contents of your single.php & sidebar.php

Comment: @Davis Thanks with your suggestion i am able to solve the problem i created a copy of sidebar.php and rename it as sidebar-single.php and in my single.php i did the following thing <?php get_sidebar('single'); ?> i hope i am followed the right approach?

Comment: You did, my friend! Have a read up on the tempting system in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates